# Parallax in listview and Fragment

Tags: android, listview, parallax

I am looking for any good solution to make parallax with two Views.

My first view is Fragment and second is ListView.

Fragment have min height equals 200dp and when I want drag listview to down the fragment will grow.

I wrote some code, but it isn't all I need.

```
public class MyListView extends ListView implements OnTouchListener {

    int touchActionDownY, touchActionMoveY;

    int parentHeight;
    int initialPosition = -1;

    TextView viewToMove;
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params;

    public MyListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public MyListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public MyListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    private void init () {
        setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        parentHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        initialPosition = (int) getY();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        int deltaY = 0;

        switch (event.getAction()) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            touchActionDownY = (int)event.getY();
            touchActionMoveY = touchActionDownY;
            break; 

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            break; 

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

            deltaY = (int)event.getY() - touchActionMoveY;

            touchActionMoveY = (int)event.getY();


            if(getFirstVisiblePosition() == 0 && v.getY() < parentHeight && touchActionMoveY > touchActionDownY && deltaY > 0){
                params.height = params.height + deltaY;
                viewToMove.setLayoutParams(params);
                return true;
            } else if(v.getY() > 200 && touchActionMoveY < touchActionDownY && deltaY < 0) {
                params.height = params.height + deltaY;;
                viewToMove.setLayoutParams(params); 
                return true;
            } else {

            }

            break; 
        } 

        return false;
    }   


    public void setViewToMove(TextView v) {
        viewToMove = v;
        params = (android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams) viewToMove.getLayoutParams();

    }

}
```

In this ListView I need smooth view scroll when user throw list. (View stoped, because method work with ACTION_MOVE).

Any help?

I need interaction with my first fragment.

Parallax should work when only list is draged.

Comment: Sorry, but your question seems very vague to me. Where exactly are you facing an issue? If you are looking for help in general in making a parallax listview, I would suggest you have a look at how they implemented it in any of these parallax listviews here http://www.appance.com/category/android/?tag=parallax. If you are facing a specific issue, you might want to edit the question to make that clear.